# Cannot resolve mostly all classes from AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, dsl

I have a project with different flavors.

I have a `card_layout.xml` file in all flavors

```
...
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_promotion_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="184dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
...
```

When I'm trying to build app I'm getting an error "Cannot resolve class androidx.cardview.widget.CardView".

And that's strange because I have dependency `implementation("androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0")` in my **build.gradle.kts** file

The same errors I have for Fragment, RecyclerView and so on.

Also I've noticed that `classes.jar` are empty inside these libraries.
Does anyone know, where the problem can be?

P.S. I can post additional info if you need.
P.S2. I tried Invalidate & Restart. Deleting .gradle and .idea folders. It doesn't help.

Comment: Did you try to delete `.gradle` folder and then resync? if not working you may need to delete `.idea` and re-import the project in Android studio

Comment: @Jagar tried. No changes..